# adding .on to jQuery .16.1

Tags: jquery

I'm in a situation where I need to run jQuery 1.6.1 for a CMS, however the upload plugin we're using uses jQuery 1.7's .on function.

I was wondering if there was a way we can extend our 1.6 to include .on functionality.

Many thanks

Comment: interesting problem... could you either find an alternate plugin or simply upgrade from 1.6.1 to 1.7.2?

Comment: @dystroy - I think the OP means a plugin he is using requires `.on()` (within the plugin itself - not the implementation)

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/ "For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see ..."

Comment: Well the we cant find another plugin, its universal for all our websites, but a client request means we need to use 1.6. On the initiation of the plugin we do $('#id').uploader(stuff{}).on('complete'); this is their documentation usage instructions. However we tried swapping the .on for .live however it didnt even trigger console.log(1)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have other non-forward compatible plugins I don't really see the point of not upgrading to a more recent jQuery version.

Nevertheless, here's an attempt at monkey patching, taking advantage of the similarity between signatures. This is likely to be brittle though, so you might have to compensate for other signatures as well, depending on how the plugin uses `on`.

```
jQuery.fn.extend( {
        on: function(eventsmap, selector, data, handler) {
            return this.delegate(selector, eventsmap, data, handler)
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After @looper suggested to re-reead http://api.jquery.com/on/ I tried using .one and sure enough it actually worked. Not entirely sure why but it does.

So if you ever need to use .on on 1.6 give .one a try!